# count down in jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to make a simple count down like 1% then it replace with 2% and so on.. in  my jsp page.
Actually i want to show progress of a process. Is any one can help me..

Thanks

Comment: What kind of process do you want to monitor/display? Is this some kind of background job that runs on the server?

Comment: yes i am just doing server side job and i water mark the current page for some time while my job is in process and i want to show the progress of submitted job.and after that i again show the current page.

Comment: hi i am waiting for your response...

Comment: As I said in my answer, I would display the progress using the jquery ui progress bar. You can either update the progress each time the "marked" page gets loaded or you can additionally provide updates via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the progress bar component of jquery ui: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

If the process you want to monitor runs on the server, you might have to have some kind of javascript background job, that asks the server for the current progress every say 3-5 seconds and updates the progress bar.